# How to play FLV files using VideoJs?

Tags: video, video.js, flv

Trying to set-up videojs to play videos, however the videos are usually external links and not always local files.
All of this is read from a feed and I don't know without downloading the file what type of video it is, whether it's an mp4, flv or other. I could try path extension with PHP, however not all URLs include an extension. Some can be like: http://example.com/videos/?id=290

In `<head>` I have:

```
<base href="/">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/video.dev.js"></script>
<script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "/js/video-js.swf";
</script>
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="multimedia_video lazy" data-href="#vid-href_78" data-vid-id="vid_78"
    data-vid-src="http://mobile2.swissgeo.ch/neuchatel/imotion/images/videos/creux-du-van.flv"
    data-original="http://mobile2.swissgeo.ch/neuchatel/imotion/images/videos/alt_CreuxduVan.jpg" style="display: block; background-image: url(http://mobile2.swissgeo.ch/neuchatel/imotion/images/videos/alt_CreuxduVan.jpg);">
    <div class="multimedia_title categoryGrey">
        Creux du Van
    </div>

    <div class="hide">
        <div id="vid-href_78" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS is:

```
$('.multimedia_video').colorbox({
    inline: true,
    innerWidth: '95%',
    innerHeight: '40%',
    href: function() {
        return $(this).data('href');
    },
    title: function() {
        return $('.multimedia_title', this).text();
    },
    onLoad: function() {
        var vidId = $(this).data('vid-id');
        var vidImage = $(this).data('original');
        var vidSrc = $(this).data('vid-src');
        var href = $(this).data('href');

        var vidAttrib = {
            'id': vidId,
            'class': 'video-js vjs-default-skin',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'poster': vidImage,
            'preload': 'auto',
            'data-setup': '{}'
        };
        var vidElem = $('<video/>').attr(vidAttrib);

        var sourceFlv = {
            'src': vidSrc,
            'type': 'video/flv'
        };
        var sourceWebm = {
            'src': vidSrc,
            'type': 'video/webm'
        };
        var sourceMp4 = {
            'src': vidSrc,
            'type': 'video/mp4'
        };

        vidElem.append($('<source/>').attr(sourceFlv));
        vidElem.append($('<source/>').attr(sourceWebm));
        vidElem.append($('<source/>').attr(sourceMp4));
        $(href).html(vidElem);

        videojs.players = {};
        videojs(vidId, {
            language: 'fr',
            techOrder: ["html5", "flash"],
            controls: true,
            autoplay: true,
            preload: "auto"
        }, function() {
        });
    },
    onCleanup: function() {
        var vidId = $(this).data('vid-id');
        videojs(vidId).dispose();
        videojs.players = {};
    }
});
```

I have it working now, however I need videoJs to check if video works in HTML then use HTML otherwise try the flash player... instead it seems to only try HTML and when it fails it just outputs the error.